# Java application framework on the web

Tags: java, applet, webserver

I'm making a sort of Webserver that enables a user to give .jow file and then when a web browser ask for that file a view will be generated and shown.

Now my question is:

> In what do I need to generate the view?

Do I need to use html, css, or javascript?

Do I need to write a part of special applets?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Showing my ignorance, but what's a .jow file?

Comment: What I want to do is make application's that sends events to the webserver and the webserver handles and send data bank the scripts where the logic are in are .jow file's. Hope this clear some things up :)

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. There are a great many web technologies for Java and it's difficult to recommend one based on this little information. I recommend starting with [the Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) on web applications.

Comment: Ok, no problem, I will try and see what I can make myself and when there pop's some error's I will post them here :)

Comment: Not really. Makes the question more interesting though. So let me see if I've got this right... you are creating (i) some sort of application that captures events from something and passes them onto the webserver in some way? (ii) something on that webserver that acts as a service endpoint for the client to send events to and (iii) something that when called processes/interprets one of these .jow files, formats some output as appropriate and then returns it to the client?  What format is the client expecting to get the data in?  Is it meant to be human or machine-readable?

Comment: Look for tutorials on JAX-RS and Jersey, but that's just a guess, because I agree with the earlier comment that this question is either too broad or too vague.

Comment: @Trevor - A .jow file is his creation I believe. I imagine that .jow files are templates in a spec of his design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what you do, the "view" will have to output [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) in the end. In a nutshell, web pages are HTML documents and that is the language that web browsers understand.

HTML dictates what you will see on the page and how various page elements relate to each other. As Scott Hanselman is [fond of saying](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode20AWebFrameworkForEveryLanguage.aspx), you are creating an angle-bracket generator. HTML, like XML and SGML, uses a lot of angle brackets.

CSS and JavaScript are "optional" technologies that you can layer on top of HTML. My apologies if my explanation is too obvious. Your question is quite broad.

[CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) is a language (but not really a programming language) that instructs the browser how to "present" the HTML. CSS controls things like color, size, position, etc of your HTML. CSS is what allows your HTML to adapt to different devices, screen sizes or even different media (such as on-screen vs print). CSS also controls some simple "behaviour" such as how HTML elements should react when you hover over them and the like. These days, CSS can even be used to create animation.

[JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) is a programming languages that allows you to manipulate your HTML to create complex behaviours beyond the capabilities of HTML and CSS. Typically, JavaScript is used to implement more dynamic or interactive features. In particular, AJAX is the technology that has enabled what some people call Web 2.0 applications. These days the combination of modern JavaScript, AJAX, CSS, and HTML is often simply called HTML5.

Most web application frameworks that I have seen primarily generate HTML but the fancier ones do generate JavaScript for you as well. For example, a common "enhancement" is to allow the creation of HTML links (anchors) that act like buttons. Often, there is some boiler-plate CSS created just to make the default output prettier but mostly the CSS is left up to the end-user to craft.

So, your view is simply going to output HTML. If you want to be buzz-word compliant, say that it generates HTML5!

Now, all I have done is tell you what to generate. Your actual question was what you need to generate it. Well, it sounds like you are writing a Java framework. The answer then is that you would use Java to generate the view. So, what do you write in Java?

Well, you need some kind of template engine that generates HTML (or HTML5) from the templates that your users write. You need a framework that sits under your "views". I presume that you will be creating an [MVC framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) so another thing that you will need to provide is the code and conventions to support the easy creation of "controllers". You will also need to integrate your framework into a web-server (or write a web-server yourself as your title suggests) so that the framework can be called when somebody requests a ".jow" file. If you are doing MVC, the general best practice is to have the controller get called first and for it to decide which view to return.

A basic explanation of how to create a web server in java can be found [here](http://onjava.com/onjava/2003/04/23/java_webserver.html) (and a lot of other places).

Or...you could just use one of the many [Java web frameworks](http://java-source.net/open-source/web-frameworks) that already exist.

Comment: Strictly speaking the returned content doesn't *HAVE* to be HTML, it just needs to have the appropriate content type set in the HTTP header and the browser should find the right thing to interpret it or display it with some default renderer.

Comment: @Trevor - Ok, I will upvote you because you are right of course. For example, the view could be nothing but static PNG (image) files, video files, WAV files (audio) for the blind, or even just simple text. You can also write plug-ins like Flash or Silverlight to extend the browser however you want. That said, it is hard to imagine a web application framework that does not, in the main, simply generate HTML. Anybody benefiting from my answer is probably well served by the simplification. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type for extra homework I guess.